# magento 2 return Id of saved repository model

Tags: magento2

I want to get the `id/data` of the saved resource model.

I am using a repository as the link between my model and the resource model.

**This is my method:**

it saved the model using the resource model.

```
public function save(dataInterface $object): resourceModel
    {
        try {
            if ($object->getId()) {
                $object = $this->getById($object->getId())->addData($object->getData());
            }
            $object  =  $this->resourceModel->save($object);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($object->getId()) {
                throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                    __(
                        'Unable to save view with ID %1. Error: %2',
                        [$object->getId(), $e->getMessage()]
                    )
                );
            }
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Unable to save new view. Error: %1', $e->getMessage()));
        }
        return $object;
    }
```

How I implement the above method:

```
$model = $objectManager->create('my\test\Model\TheModelFactory')->create();

$modelRepostory = $objectManager->create('my\test\Api\TheModelRepositoryInterface');

$model->setComment("no comment");

$object = $modelRepostory->save($model);

var_dump($object->getId());
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method my\test\Model\ResourceModel\TheModel::getId()
```

Answer (score 0):

The ResourceModel dosn't hold any data of your saved Model.

But if you want to access the Id of your saved Model, just change

```
$object  =  $this->resourceModel->save($object);
```

to

```
$this->resourceModel->save($object);
```

and you can access the ID of the saved $object afterwards by calling `$object->getId();`

When saving a new object, the resourceModel assigns the generated ID to $object.

Comment: Hello @Ekk4rd.Thanks for help. i tried your solution but it does not work. the object is being returned before its saved. so the getID() returns null. do you have an example of returning